# Select the 2 latest records from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have data like in this mysql table:

```
id  customer_id  date  price
1       A        2014-01-01      4
2       A        2014-02-01      3
3       B        2014-03-01      2.5
4       B        2014-04-01      1
5       B        2014-05-01      5
6       C        2014-06-01      2
7       D        2014-07-01      2
8       D        2014-08-01      2.5
9       D        2014-09-01      1
```

I want to get the latest two dates for customer_id A, B and D. My result should be like this:

```
id  customer_id  date  price
1       A        2014-01-01      4
2       A        2014-02-01      3
4       B        2014-04-01      1
5       B        2014-05-01      5
8       D        2014-08-01      2.5
9       D        2014-09-01      1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way :

```
SELECT *
FROM   test s
WHERE  (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    test  f
            WHERE f.customer_id = s.customer_id AND 
                  f.`date` >= s.`date`
        ) <= 2
        AND customer_id  in('A','B','D');
```

**[[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef153b/1)]**

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just updated the problem, its a little bit different. Do you mind to take a look again?

Comment: No. The latest update shows an entirely different problem, and different problem should goes in new question

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
select * from table where customer_id  in('A','B','D') order by date desc limit 2
```